# Errors in implementation file

Tags: ios

Have a few errors in my implementation file which keep me from compiling, but I can't figure them out. Thanks in advance for your help.

Have commented out the error messages:

Implementation file:

```
#import "TNRViewController.h"

@implementation TNRViewController //'@end' is missing in implementation context

@synthesize myIcon, myBackground, bgImages, shrinkButton;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
hasMoved = NO;
    hasShrunk = NO;
    currentBackground = 0;

    bgImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_01.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_02.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_03.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_04.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"WallPaper_05.png"],
                nil];

    size = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.25, .25);
    translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-100);

    myBackground.image = [bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myIcon release];
    [myBackground release];
    [shrinkButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([myIcon frame], [touch locationInView:nil])); // if statement has empty body
    {
        if (hasMoved == YES && hasShrunk == YES) {
            myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(size, 0, 0);
            hasMoved = NO;
    }
        if (hasMoved == YES && hasShrunk == NO) {
            myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
            hasMoved = NO;
    }
        myIcon.center = [touch locationInView:nil];
    }

}

- (IBAction)shrink:(id)sender {
    if (hasShrunk) {
        [shrinkButton setTitle:@"Shrink" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [shrinkButton setTitle:@"Grow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if (hasShrunk == NO && hasMoved == NO) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = size;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasShrunk = YES;
    }

    else if (hasShrunk == NO && hasMoved == YES) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, .25, .25);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasShrunk = YES;
    }

    else if (hasShrunk == YES && hasMoved == YES) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 1, 1);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasShrunk = NO;
    }

    else {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasShrunk = NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)move:(id)sender {
    if (hasMoved == NO && hasShrunk == NO) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = translate;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasMoved = YES;
    }
        else if (hasMoved == NO && hasShrunk == YES){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(size, 0, -100);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasMoved = YES;
    }
        else if (hasMoved == YES && hasShrunk == YES){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(size, 0, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasMoved = YES;
    }
        else
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasMoved = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)change:(id)sender {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground >= [bgImages count]) 
        currentBackground = 0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"changeview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    if (currentBackground == 1) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES]; 

    if (currentBackground == 2) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES]; 

    if (currentBackground == 3) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES]; 

    if (currentBackground == 4) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [myBackground.image = [bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground]; //Expected identifier

}
```

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TNRViewController : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *myIcon;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *myBackground;
    IBOutlet UIButton *shrinkButton;

    NSArray *bgImages;
    int currentBackground;
    bool hasMoved;
    bool hasShrunk;

    CGAffineTransform translate;
    CGAffineTransform size;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *myIcon;
@property (retain, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *myBackground;
@property (retain, nonatomic)NSArray *bgImages;
@property (retain, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *shrinkButton;

- (IBAction)shrink:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)move:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)change:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Is your question really supposed to be: How do I fix `'@end' is missing in implementation context`?

Comment: Yes, I can't figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the errors you commented on your source files.

First:

```
@implementation TNRViewController //'@end' is missing in implementation context
```

That means that you are missing an @`end` at the end of the `.m` file.

Second:

```
[myBackground.image = [bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground]; //Expected identifier
```

Should be:

```
myBackground.image = [bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground];
```

Third:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint([myIcon frame], [touch locationInView:nil])); // if statement has empty body
```

Should be

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint([myIcon frame], [touch locationInView:nil])) // Remove the semi column
```